# AngularJS $watch isn't being fired when watch variable is updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of products on my ProductsController that I'm trying to update with a $watch. However, productsService.products watch only fires on the initialization of the array.

```
app.controller("ProductsController",
[
    "$scope", "$q", "productsService", "httpRepository",
    function($scope, $q, productsService, httpRepository) {
        $scope.productsService = productsService;
        $scope.products = [];

        $scope.$watch("productsService.products",
            function (newVal, oldVal) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.products = newVal;
                });

            }, true);

        $scope.productsService.getProducts();

    }
]);

app.service("productsService",
["httpRepository", "$q", function (httpRepository, $q) {

    var products = [];
    //populates the products.
    const getProducts = function () {
        httpRepository.getProducts().then(function (result) {
            products = result.data.Products; });
    };
    
    return {
        getProducts: getProducts,
        products: products
    };
}
]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are watching the products array of the productsService for changes in values, create a reference to the array itself in your scope:

instead of:

```
$scope.productsService = productsService;
```

try:

```
$scope.productsService = productsService.products;
```

and:

```
$scope.$watch("productsService",
   function (newVal, oldVal) {...
```